# Save id to local storage with button angularjs

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

i use a favorite button to my project. Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hfVDt1DKhUiwNwyLBLT?p=preview)

script.js

```
angular.module("MyApp",[]);
```

service.js

```
angular
.module("MyApp")
.service("FavoriteService",[function(){


//Favorites functions
this.isLocalStorageEnable = function() {

    if(typeof (Storage) !== "undefined"){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};

this.isFavorite = function(scope){
    var fav = localStorage.getItem(scope.id);
    return fav === "1";
};


this.setFav = function(scope){
    localStorage.setItem(scope.id,"1");

};


this.deleteFav = function(scope){
    localStorage.removeItem(scope.id);

};


 }]);
```

directive.js

```
angular.module("MyApp").directive("albumDirective",    ["FavoriteService", function(FavoriteService) {

return {
restrict: "AE",
templateUrl: "AlbumDirective.html",
replace: true,
scope: {
    id: "=albumId"
},
  link: function(scope)
     {
      scope.isLocalStorageEnable = FavoriteService.isLocalStorageEnable;
      scope.isFavorite = FavoriteService.isFavorite(scope);

    scope.markAs = function(type) {
      switch(type) {
        case true :
          FavoriteService.setFav(scope);
          break;
        case false : 
          FavoriteService.deleteFav(scope);
          break;

      }
      scope.isFavorite = type;
    }

}

  };

  }]);
```

AlbumDirective.html

```
        <button ng-click="markAs(!isFavorite)" ><i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-heart' : isFavorite , 'fa-heart-o' : !isFavorite }"></i></button>
```

Itempage.html

```
<album-directive album-id="1"></album-directive>
```

When i click the heart button for in ItemPage.html for item 1 the button become active and when i navigate again to ItemPage.html  for item 2 the button is already active.In each item page i have {{object.itemid}} .I would like to add the itemid to local storage so the button will be active only when the button pressed for each item. i Never used local storage.Any suggestions?Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what is the item id for item2? your example seems to be working fine and there should not be any problem as long as each item has different id

Comment: The item 1 has itemid=1, the item1 has itemid=2 when i am at itempage and view the item 1 and click the button to set the item1 to favorite is work. However when i go back ang go to itempage.html to view the item2  the button is already active. So there is only one state for all items ( active or not). I need one state for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Antonis,

Angular services are singletons and therefore are instantiated only once through the life cycle of the application. Meaning that they are great for storing and sharing data across controllers.

**Local Storage**

> [The localStorage object](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

Hence, the behavior. Opening multiple web pages will access the same local storage, itself a singleton.

The difference is that with angular, every page that is open has its own instance of the application. Therefore each webpage will have it's own instance of the service.

**Solution**

[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdtaYFTIKdiFz4csTF5O?p=preview)

**The Code**

```
angular.module("MyApp").service("FavoriteService",[function(){


  this.fav = 0;

  //Favorites functions
  this.isLocalStorageEnable = function() {

      if(typeof (Storage) !== "undefined"){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  };

  this.isFavorite = function(scope){
      return this.fav === 1;
  };

  this.setFav = function(){
      this.fav = 1;

  };

  this.resetFav = function(){
      this.fav = 0;

  };

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This solution is not resolve the problem.i have already the same problem (the button is active in all pages),Also now the button is active and when click again stay active.

Comment: I'm using the plunker in Chrome and it works like a charm. Are you using this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MdtaYFTIKdiFz4csTF5O?p=preview

Comment: yes.When i click the button become active  and then is active for all items

Comment: My apologies. The button is active once it is set because if you have more than one item using the same service they will use the same variable value. You may want to have a service variable per item. In this case because there may be so many items then an array would work, or a list of some kind